# Use already compiled Protobuf-classes in new .proto-files

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have imported a library which contains classes generated by protobuf.

I would like to send objects of this class as part of other protobuf messages. But `protoc` (obviously?) complains about missing definitions:

> Couldn't resolve reference to Type 'ExistingProtobufLibraryClass'.

I could of course *copy* the existing .proto source from the source of the library, but then I suspect that protoc will generate *two* versions of this class, which would be quite annoying.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you played with the various "import" options in protoc/.proto?

Comment: Yeah.. I can import the proto-def of the already compiled class and it works. If I could only tell protoc *not* to generate code for it it would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the existing proto class.

```
import "somepath/existing_protobuf_library_class.proto"
```

protoc won't generate additional code, the generated Java code will just import the assumed other classes.